# Custom Control (Show properties of another object)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c#-express-2010

How can I get the properties of another control to show up in properties window. For example if I have

```
public class MyClass : UserControl
{
    public MyClass(){}
    public bool Visible{get;set}// Property of MyClass

    public MyProperties GridProp {get;set;}// Tried this but does not show the properties 
                                 //of MyProperties class

}

public class MyProperties
{
    public MyProperties() { }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get `MyProperties` properties to show up with the properties of `MyClass`?

Comment: Is it declared as `public MyProperties{get;set;}`, because that won't compile? It needs to by `public MyProperties MyProperties {get;set;}`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I corrected it. It should be public myProperties GridProp {get;set;}

Answer (score 2):

If you want your properties to show up in the VS properties window you have to add some attributes to the property in qestion.

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        MyObject = new MyObject();
    }

    [Category("MyControl")]
    [Description("My Property Description")]
    [TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public MyObject MyObject { get; set; }
}


public class MyObject
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

You have to decorate you custom object with the ExpandableObjectConverter Typeconverter, this will show the properites in the class.

[image]

There are attributes to set the displayname, category, and things like default value. more info can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx